# Replace a string in a column for each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

**Edit: I had to add this part to my original question as it's relevant.**

I have a frame which contains many different prefixes in the name column called `dfload`.

I use the following command to create a slice called `df`.

`df = dfload.loc[dfload['Name'].str.contains("testData/")]`

**Original Question continues from here:**

Then, I have the following pandas dataframe called `df`,

```
   name               etc etc etc
0  testData/example1  etc ...
1  testData/example2  ...
2  testData/example3
3  testData/example4
...
```

I want to replace the string `testData/` with nothing for the entire column so it looks like this

```
   name      etc etc etc
0  example1  etc ...
1  example2  ...
2  example3
3  example4
...
```

I used the following command `df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('testData/','')`.

But I get this error,

```
<ipython-input-20-dae746394d2d>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('testData/','')
```

The dataframe looks fine, why am I getting this error? What's the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: it's not really an error, though, it's a warning.

Comment: will I run into problems if I keep doing it this way then?

Comment: you shouldn't, but you might be able to suppress the warning with
`df.loc[:,['name']] = df.name.str.replace('testdata/','')`

Comment: ok I think it's happening because I made this frame from a slice of another frame, is that why? I used this command `df = dfload.loc[dfload['Name'].str.contains("testData/")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid the warning that you're getting, create `df` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dfload[dfload.name.str.contains('testdata/')])
```

specifying that it's a dataframe and not a slice is probably what keeps pandas from throwing the warning

Comment: I've never made slices that way, it works!. learned something new thanks

Comment: @anarchy I think that the majority of the work was actually figuring out how to reproduce the warning.  Thank you for showing me the precise origin of a warning that pandas has given me many times.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df.name = df.name.str.replace('testData/','',regex = True)
```

Comment: It is a warning btw, and not an error. Is this your whole code?

Comment: I updated my question, I think its the previous command I used that's causing this. could you take a look

Answer (score 0):

You should try using lamda funtion to apply the replace statement over every row:

```
df["name"]= df.apply(lambda x: x['name'].replace('testData/',''), axis=1)
```